# postCreateCommand in VSCode Remote Container Development doesn't show Azure Cli output

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers, azure-cli

I'm running a bash script as postCreateCommand when building a VSCode remote development container. In this bash script the command is `az login`. The problem is that there is not output from this command and therefore I cannot login the Azure CLI. When ran manually in the terminal, it works.

devcontainer.json has this command:
`"postCreateCommand": "bash .devcontainer/install.sh",`

install.sh has only one line:
`az login`

The expected output is to be asked by Azure CLI to login on `microsoft.com/devicelogin` using a code.

The VSCode output doesn't show any Azure CLI output; it only tells that the `install.sh` script is being executed and it waits until the `az login` command gives a timeout error and finishes.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI command `az login` is an interactive command. If you want to use it in the script without input, then you need to change it into a non-interactive command. I recommend you use the service principal to achieve it:

```
az login --service-principal -u username -p password --tenant tenantId
```

This CLI command will execute directly without input and give the output if the service principal has no problem.

Comment: Yes, that is one option but my intention is to log in the user which starts the development container so that it has access to the entire Azure through the personal account.

Comment: @tomab If your user account only has a password credential, then you can put the username and password in the script directly. But if you use the device or other authentication, then you have no choice.

Comment: @tomab Any more updates fro the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I'm reluctant to ask the user to enter the password and I cannot migrate towards a service principal for everyone. Probably the way to go, for the moment, is to ask the user to run the custom powershell script so that they can go through all its interactivity.

Comment: @tomab Well, you need to choose between the security and automatic script. But that's it. No way can combine all benefits perfectly. And if the answer solves your problem please accept it.